# Make the AppOffline file less StackOverflow-centric

Tags: bug, status-completed

The page shown when the site is being updated is rather confusing - it's very StackOverflow centric.

While I don't expect it to be customised for each and every site currently in the beta phase, it should probably be more StackExchange/Area51 based?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We now show the shared SE offline page.

Answer (score 1):

What a chance to invent our own HTTP status code! 999 - Stack Exchange Is Morphing :) I mean yes, it should be a 200/OK but the image would be appropriate for all SE sites.